# getimagedata() to particle texture three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, getimagedata

I'm trying to do this: getimagedata() from diferent positions of the same canvas elemente and make each of the imagedata chunks to be the texture of individuals particles in a particle system. I dont want the all the system to have the same texture, rather each particle's texture has to correspond to a a chunk of the image on the canvas. Once I have my imgData[i] array filled with the information, how can I assign each of its elements to the texture value of each particle? (remember, I want each particle to have a different texture that corresponds to each element in the imgData[i] array )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParticleSystem` only supports a single texture for all particles in the system, and all particles share that texture.

Comment: hey west, can I simulate a a particle system using sprites?

Comment: [see this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_particles_sprites.html).